# Como criar interface gráfica em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gente, conheço o básico de python e queria saber se é possível criar interface gráfica para os programas que faço nele. Algo como aquela interface que da pra fazer no VBA. Eu consigo fazer isso no python mesmo? Ou da pra usar outro programa pra fazer a parte gráfica e o python só ficar por trás?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sim, o python tem varias bibliotecas, Tkinter,PyQt,PySide,Kivy,PyGtk,Wxpython dentre outras ,porem aconselho a nao 'perder' tempo estudando o tkinter, pois é bastante limitada.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo bem? Se você é acostumado com VBA, VB e C# talvez renda bem usando o [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/community/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) que é gratuito e usa IronPython para criar formulários e programas em modo visual.

Outras alternativa é o [Glade Interface Designer](https://glade.gnome.org/) ou o [PAGE](http://page.sourceforge.net/)
Se estiver usando Linux pode dar uma olhada no Auto Glade.

Mesmo o Tkinter sendo um pouco limitado o [Canal Ignorância Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZXth4l6DCs&list=PLfCKf0-awunOu2WyLe2pSD2fXUo795xRe&index=88) no YouTube tem ótimas aulas em português de como usar.

O [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) da dicas de Gui Programming com diversos pacotes para desenvolvimento de GUI, na última tabela (lá pro final da página) tem vários IDEs com desenvolvimento visual.

Comment: O kivy sugerido pelo @karllos é um ótimo pacote pra investir pois ele te possibilita gerar aplicativos pra android e outras plataformas!